# distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

When we say that we have ordered distinct eigenvalues. Does that mean that the the eigenvalues are decreasing $\lambda_1 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_p$ or strictly decreasing $\lambda_1 > \cdots > \lambda_p$  ?

Comment: We refer $\geq$, not $>$.

Answer (score 2):

If the $\lambda_i$ represent **all** of the eigenvalues, then the first notation is correct, since you will have equality where there are repeated eigenvalues and the order is not strict.

But if the $\lambda_i$ represent only the **distinct** eigenvalues, then the second notation is correct, since distinct means that the repeats are not included and the order is strict.

For example, if the eigenvalues are $3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1,$ then you would order the **distinct** eigenvalues as $3>2>1$. You could order **all** of the eigenvalues as $3\geq 3\geq 3\geq 2\geq 1\geq 1$.